# Can I use $.ajaxSetup() to enforce utf-8 character encoding on a (non-ajax) form post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a form that I'm posting with the help of jQuery:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="/processForm">
    <input type="text" name="inputs" id="inputs"/>
    <button id="submitButton">Submit Form</button>
</form>

$('#submitButton').click( function(event)
{
    if(formValidatesOk())
    {
        $("#myForm").submit();
    }
}
```

But according to the headers reported by Firebug when the form is posted, no character encoding header is being submitted with the form - only this:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Could I use ajaxSetup to enforce utf-8 character encoding:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
        scriptCharset: "utf-8" , 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

I'm not sure if this is possible since I'm not using jQuery ajax here - I'm simply calling `submit` on the form?

Answer (score 0):

Using `$.ajaxSetup` will only affect reqeusts sent via jQuery+AJAX. You can submit the form via AJAX when the user clicks submit, then redirect to another page when the request is returned to enforce utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, it just doesn't work this way.  [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) really just extends the [`$.ajaxSettings`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/ajax.js#L169-195) object which all [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (and [the shorthand versions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/)) use when they execute...it has *no* effect on any other type of server request, it's exclusively for jQuery's ajax operations (or anything built on them)...but doesn't at all effect default `<form>` behavior in the page.